# Reverting hidden section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder if anyone understands my weird explanation...
I have a hidden section setup like this:

```
<section class="intro">
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="menu">
    <span class="hamburger"></span>
  </span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</label>
</section>

<section class="invis">
</section>

.invis {
  display:none;
}
```

When a "button" is pressed, the section should be visible again so basically default: hidden, when you click the section is visible and when you close the section, the section should go back to display:none. Here comes the weird explanation (the weird part is in between the "** **":

```
label input:checked + .menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #E0C9B7, 0 0 0 100vh #E0C9B7;
  border-radius: 0;
  **display: .invis**;
}
```

How could I achive this? I would appreciate a code example

Comment: And the css you provided doesn't make sense (`label input:checked + .menu` - How is this related to the question)

Comment: Use jQuery [$("section").toggleClass("invis");](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) when you click the button. You may want to add an id to the section so you can select it easily.

Comment: if checkbox is right before/after section you could use the same "next sibling" + or "some sibling" ~ operators. If checkbox and section are placed in completely different places of DOM then it's impossible to implement with CSS only.

Comment: Everything under label input:checked + .menu is shown when the button is pressed and I am trying to find a way so that when the checkbox is checked it should show the hidden section

Comment: what happened to the `.invis` section?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4h86b8ep/ created a fiddle, note that when you open the menu, it goes over the second section, it needs to only fill the first section

Comment: and the `.invis` section?

Comment: It is removed in the fiddle in case there is a simple solution, in the fiddle you can see that when I would add .invis in between the intro and first, the menu would fill intro and invis but invis shouldnt display when the menu is not open, this was my solution but maybe there is another solution to fix the menu only to the intro section

Comment: yah, I think I did it!  Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4h86b8ep/2/  you should also update you question so that it asks what you showed in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how CSS works. You can achieve this by simply toggling a class on and off via the button click:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".menu").classList.toggle("invis");
});
```

```css
.invis {
  display:none;
}

label input:checked + .menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #E0C9B7, 0 0 0 100vh #E0C9B7;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="menu invis">
    <span class="hamburger">Hamburger Icon Here</span>
  </span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</label>
</section>
```

Comment: @Sheila I have updated the answer to use a checkbox, but you haven't shown any HTML that matches with `label input:checked + .menu`.

Comment: @Sheila Please edit your question to show the code you are working with. Right now, it's quite unclear what you have.

Comment: @Sheila It's still not entirely clear what is supposed to be shown/hidden. I think your HTML structure needs to be re-thought.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/4h86b8ep created a fiddle, note that when you open the menu, it goes over the second section, it needs to only fill the first section

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this may be what you need. I changed the 2 following css selectors.

```
label input:checked + .menu {
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #FFF, 0 0 0 100vh #FFF;*/
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 35px;
  right:25px
}
```

```css
/* Section styling */
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  height: 100vh;
}

.intro {
  background-color:#291411;
}

.first {
  background-color:#834940;
}

.second {
  background-color:#291411;
}

.third {
  background-color:#834940;
}
/* Hide scrollbars */
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px; 
    background: transparent; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
/* Menu before */
label .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  right: 125px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

label .hamburger:after, label .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

label .hamburger:before { top: -10px; }

label .hamburger:after { bottom: -10px; }

label input { display: none; }

label input:checked + .menu {
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #FFF, 0 0 0 100vh #FFF;*/
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 35px;
  right:25px
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
}

label input:checked + .menu + ul { opacity: 1; }
/* Menu after */
label .menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 0 0 #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label ul {
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
}

label a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Footer styling */
footer {
  padding: 1% 5%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #291411;
  color: #E0C9B7;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="menu">
    <span class="hamburger"></span>
  </span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</label>
</section>

<section class="first"> 
first
</section>

<section class="second">  
second
</section>


<section class="third">  
 third
</section>
```

Corrected fiddle if needed: https://jsfiddle.net/4h86b8ep/2/

Comment: It's really important to avoid using `!important`.

Comment: lol... nicely put.  Will update

Comment: @Sheila did this solve your problem, or are you still having issues?